# executing java program from command line in windows fails

Tags: java, exception, cmd, javac, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to run a very simple one class "Hello World" program from the command line in Windows.

The `.java` file is located at "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\direcName". The package is `deem` and the class name is `test`.

I can cd to the directory and compile it from there using `javac test.java` and that works perfectly fine. However, when I try to run it using:

`java test` or `java -classpath directory test` or `java -cp . test`
it throws "Exception in thread `main` `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test (wrong name: deem/test)`.

If I use java `deem.test` it says: `Error, could not find or load main class deem.main`

How can I fix the exception and get my program to run?

Thanks

Comment: Can please share the `test` source code...

Comment: You can cd to which directory? Please describe the directory structure you are using.

Answer (score 5):

This is a variation of the "common beginners error" with running Java programs from the command line.

> java test or java -classpath directory test or java -cp . test it throws "Exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test (wrong name: deem/test).

The JVM is in effect telling you that found "test.class" on the search path, but when it read class file, it concluded that the file *should* have been at "./deem/test.class" or "directory/deem/test.class" ... depending on which "-cp" / "-classpath" argument you *actually* used

> If I use java deem.test it says: Error, could not find or load main class deem.main

This is now telling you that it cannot find "deem/main.class".

Note that you have *now* told it to look for a class called "deem.main" instead of "test" or "deem.test".  (Or perhaps you just transcribed something incorrectly there.)

The rules are really rather simple:

1. You must give the **fully qualified** class name to `java` as the first argument after the options.  (*Not* the simple class name.  *Not* the ".class" file name. *Not* the name of the entry point method.)
2. You must specify the classpath such that the `java` command can

   - map the class name into a relative pathname for the class file (e.g. `foo.bar.baz.MyClass` maps to `foo/bar/baz/MyClass.class`) ...
   - and then resolve that relative path against one of the classpath entries; e.g. if `.` is the classpath, then `./foo/bar/baz/MyClass.class`.
3. The class must have the required `public static void main(String[])` entry point method.

So **IF** ...

1. the fully qualified class name of your class is `deem.test`; i.e. the `test` class is in the package `deem`, **AND**
2. the corresponding class file is in `./deem/test.class`, **AND**
3. it has the required entry point method, **AND**
4. the test application doesn't depend on other classes of yours or 3rd party libraries ...

**THEN** `java -cp . deem.test` should work.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is located in a package "deem", then you need to include the package name like this.

```
java deem.test
```

That should work.

Comment: It was mentioned in the question that he tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work. It can't find the class when I do it that way.

Comment: Also make sure that there is `public static void main(String args[])` method in your test class

Comment: Does `test.class` have to be in a `deem` directory?

Comment: @poeticcrayons Make sure the command line file isn't being run in the folder with the .class. It needs to be run outside of the package folder.

Comment: no it doesn't have to be in "deem" but I'm trying to figure out what the problem is because I actually need to run a real java program with external libraries from the cmd but I can't even get this simple one to work. When I removed the package, it executed but how can I do it with the package there?

Comment: @poeticcrayons Are you running it from outisde the package folder?

Comment: I just tried running it from outside the folder "dire" where the .class is, using java deem.test but that didn't work (couldn't find the class) and when run with java test it throws the noClassDefFound error

Comment: @poeticcrayons Try `java -cp . deem.test` then. Otherwise it's nothing java-sided you're doing wrong as long as your class has a `public static void main(String[] args)` like MadProgrammer mentioned.