# How to compile and run a Java class (Hello World example)

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I wrote a simple program that prints "Hello World". My program compiled but did not run but gave me this exception:

Exception in thread main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Hello wrong name : main hello

My program is like so:

```
package main;

public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

My program is in: \main\Hello.java
I searched so much and compiled in different ways but i don't understand what the problem is. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [executing java program from command line in windows fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773979/executing-java-program-from-command-line-in-windows-fails)

Comment: http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/21/using-javac-and-java-commands-to-compile-and-launch-java-programs/

Answer (score 0):

You should have the `Hello.java` under `main` directory as per the package definition.
So do the following.

```
d:>mkdir main
d:>move Hello.java main
d:>javac main\Hello.java
d:>java main.Hello
```

Which would print `Hello World`. This is because javac will output the .class file next to .java file by default.

If you don't want this behaviour or if you don't want to move the `.java` file, then you can also mention where the output classes needs to go.

```
d:>javac -d . Hello.java
```

This would create the `Hello.class` automatically under `main` directory as per the package definition in relevance to the current directory. Hence,

```
d:>java main.Hello
```

Which would also print `Hello World`

You can learn more about how to compile java source code [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#examples)